# size of the Custom object

Tags: apex

Below is my code:

```
  CustomObj obj = [Select id from CustomObj1];
```

How to find the size of the custom object "obj" using apex?

I tried using isEmpty() function but it shows compilation error as below

> Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Comment: Can you explain it little more in detail. What you refer in the place of size ? Do you want to check is that your query returned data? or what you want to find ?

Comment: Or are you curious the actual heap space ("size") this object will take up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression:

```
[Select id from CustomObj1__c]
```

produces a list of `CustomObj1`. That code will never produce a `null` but it may produce an empty list. (Code should only include `null` checks where nulls can occur and they can't occur here.)

You can define a variable of the right list type using either of these syntaxes; the first one is a little shorter and looks a little more symmetrical:

```
CustomObj1__c[] objects = [Select id from CustomObj1__c];
```

or:

```
List<CustomObj1__c> objects = [Select id from CustomObj1__c];
```

Once you have the `objects` variable, you can invoke any of the list methods on it including [isEmpty()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_isEmpty) and [size()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_size):

```
if (!objects.isEmpty()) {
    ...
}
```

or:

```
if (objects.size() > 0) {
    ...
}
```

or better just:

```
for (CustomObj1__c o : objects) {
    ...
}
```

or even better just:

```
for (CustomObj1__c o : [
        Select id
        from CustomObj1__c
        ]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`isEmpty()` is an instance method of [`List` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_isEmpty) and [`Set` class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm#apex_System_Set_isEmpty) so if you need to check the size with that, first it needs to be a collection of data something like `List` or `Set`.

```
List<CustomObj> objList = [Select id from CustomObj1];

if(!objList.isEmpty())
   Integer listSize = objList.size();
```

You can't apply `isEmpty()` on a sObject itself.

Comment: Suggest you remove the null check as null will never be returned.

Comment: Agreed @KeithC, updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a best practice to check for nullability on a variable that stores results from a soql query. Soql query will return null if no records exist or the criteria doesn't  return any result.

In your case it will be as follows:

```
if(objList != null) { // check size}
```